# Qt Linguist, macro and preprocessor

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Since moc object works with macro, is it possible to use the Qt Linguist with macro?

Basically, I want to achieve that :

```
#define TR1(x) QObject::tr(#x)
#define TR2(x) QObject::tr(x)
#define TR3(x) x
#define TR4 QObject::tr("Lolita4")

auto a = TR1(Lolita1);
auto b = TR2("Lolita2");
auto c = TR3(QObject::tr("Lolita3"));
auto d = TR4;
```

Here we only have the TR3 and TR4 that works. Is it possible to have TR1 and TR2 also?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that a simple `tr("foo")`, in the relevant place in your source, doesn't give you?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I want to  translate enums. For example, I have an enum `BACK, FRONT, LEFT, RIGHT` and I want to translate them. ` QMetaEnum` does not provide any way to perform translation, so I am trying to make an automatic generator of enumeration through MACRO. It works well, but translate does not work...

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have basically a macro MAKE_ENUM that we can use that way :
`MAKE_ENUM(NameOfEnumeration, ENTRY1, ENTRY2, ENTRY3)`

Comment: Both TR1 and TR2 are working in msvc 2017. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @VladimirBershov Hmmm, I am going to try. But QtLinguist does not generate the xml file properly...

Comment: @AntoineMorrier sorry but I just build and run the code, don't check linguist results...

Comment: @VladimirBershov So it works well, but the xml file is not generated automatically. I guess I must use a script that handle that for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a "tr()" macro to cheat on Qt Linguist in QObject subclass.

```
#define tr(str) QStringLiteral(str)
QString str = tr("Lolita1");
#undef tr
```

And every time you use this variable

```
QString translation = tr(str.toUtf8());
```

These two steps should be in one class.